# -Xlog:gc:/var/log/java_gc.log is not work

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image, openjdk-21

Output only to the console cannot be output to a specified log file

Reference document：https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/optimizations-and-performance/MemoryManagement/

version:

```
java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Running parameter：

```
-Xmx1G \
-Xms1G \
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=60 \
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 \
-XX:+VerboseGC \
-Xlog:gc:/var/log/java_gc.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
-H:IncludeResources=logging.properties
```

See [https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/add-logging-to-native-executable/#:~:text=%2DH%3AIncludeResources%3Dlogging.properties](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/add-logging-to-native-executable/#:%7E:text=%2DH%3AIncludeResources%3Dlogging.properties)

Comment: is not working
I went to github and asked them and this is what they said:
for reporting this issue, the -Xlog option is not supported in native image for the moment, I think it will be supported since GraalVM for JDK 23 (aka GraalVM 24.1.0).